# populating an array of varying size

Tags: java, arrays, attributes

ok I'm pretty sure this is not a clean implementation.

I have an array with attributes I must populate dependant on the attributes of an incoming object.

I have done this in a rather dirty manner and it's come back to bite me in the ass!

we ill start:

I have an `AccountsGRP[]`. I am populating between these two methods:

```
    public static AccountGrp[] popAccArr(IncomingObject incObject) {
    ArrayList<AccountGrp> accAL = new ArrayList<AccountGrp>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NoAccounts; i++) {
        accAL.add(popAccAttr(i, incObject));
    }
    AccountGrp[] AccountGrpArr = (AccountGrp[]) accAL
            .toArray(new AccountGrp[accAL.size()]);
    return AccountGrpArr;
}

private static AccountGrp popAccAttr(int i, IncomingObject incObject) {
    AccountGrp acc = new AccountGrpImpl();
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_clientAcronym());
        acc.setAccountType(AccountType.CUST);
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        acc.setGrandParentAccount(incObject.getM_grandparentNum());
        return acc;
    case 1:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_brokerAcronym());
        acc.setAccountType(AccountType.BKR);
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        // acc.setGrandParentAccount(incObject.getM_grandparentNum());
        return acc;
    case 2:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_errorAccount());
        acc.setAccountType(AccountType.FIRM);
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        acc.setAccountSubType(AccountSubType.ERROR);
        return acc;
    default:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_clientAcronym());
        acc.setAccountType(AccountType.CUST);
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        acc.setGrandParentAccount(incObject.getM_grandparentNum());
        return acc;
    }
}
```

This is bad coding I however need to populate a few different types of accounts so this case statement is inflexible and dirty. Is there an eligant implementation to this I was considering. Just writing a method with a number of parameters to take in relevant values, However the problem arises with the likes of:

```
acc.setAccountType(AccountType.BKR);
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
```

Which are returning enums. also not every account iteration populates all attributes is there a way to get optional parameters or is it just a case of overloading?

Comment: Ah, the ol' For-case structure (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm.aspx)! Always a classic when it pops up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time or mental fortitude to exactly reproduce your exact conditions, but here's a similar snippet of code that should get you started:

```
public static AccountGrp[] popAccArr(IncomingObject incObject) {
    AccountGrp[] ret = new AccountGrp[NoAccounts];

    if(ret.length > 0) {
        ret[0] = //first one
    }

    if(ret.length > 1) {
        ret[1] = //second one
    }

    if(ret.length > 2) {
        ret[2] = //third one
    }

    for(int i = 3; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = //nth one
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about arrays but rather how to map an integer (i=[0-2]) to a set of various parameters including enum values, with possibly different types of parameters for each (subtype, grandparent reference).

Overloading `popAccAttr` will not help because the caller would have to choose the correct overloading.  That just moves the problem to the caller.  You still have to map i=>params.

In my opinion the best way to clean it up is to remove the opaque integer `i`.  What does "2" mean outside of this method?  You can use an enum that provides both a list of all possible account types, and a mapping from each.  It looks like the account type itself is sufficient.  So, (also removing redundancy between "0" and "default" cases),

```
public static AccountGrp[] popAccArr(IncomingObject incObject) {
    ArrayList<AccountGrp> accAL = new ArrayList<AccountGrp>();
    for (AccountType type : AccountType.values()) { // enumerate values
        accAL.add(popAccAttr(type, incObject));
    }
    AccountGrp[] AccountGrpArr = (AccountGrp[]) accAL
            .toArray(new AccountGrp[accAL.size()]);
    return AccountGrpArr;
}

private static AccountGrp popAccAttr(AccountType type, IncomingObject incObject) {
    AccountGrp acc = new AccountGrpImpl();

    acc.setAccountType(type); // common for all

    switch (type) {
    case CUST:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_clientAcronym());
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        acc.setGrandParentAccount(incObject.getM_grandparentNum());
        break;
    case BKR:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_brokerAcronym());
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        // acc.setGrandParentAccount(incObject.getM_grandparentNum());
        break;
    case FIRM:
        acc.setAccount(incObject.getM_errorAccount());
        acc.setAcctIDSource(AcctIDSource.SLANG);
        acc.setAccountSubType(AccountSubType.ERROR);
        break;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported account type: "+type);
    }

    return accc; // common for all
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OO design is poor: you should not have a `AccountGrp[]`, it should be a class instead, with nicely named attributes..  Your code would be much more readable and maintainable.

If you want to stick with your current design, you should at least split your `popAccAttr` method.  I don't see the need to put 3 completely different methods inside one, with a case switch.

```
public static AccountGrp[] popAccArr(IncomingObject incObject) {
  AccountGrp[] accountGrp = new AccountGrp[noAccounts];
  accountGrp[0] = popAccClient(incObject);
  accountGrp[1] = popAccBroker(incObject);
  accountGrp[2] = popAccError(incObject);
  return AccountGrpArr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Start with http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DesignPatternsBook

Comment: Specifying a specific pattern to use would probably be more helpful.